# Movie: Creature crawls out of its current hosts mouth into next hosts mouth

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw part of this movie back in the 80's or early 90's on late night cable TV. I remember the cops were chasing a bad guy, and the bad guy turned out to be possessed by some sort of creature.

This creature had the ability to move from host to host by crawling down their throats (sort of like the *Edgar suit* in *Men in Black*). It may have been a bug, or a slug. I think it was black.

Comment: I've been trying to remember the name of of this movie for years. Finally googled the right questions and found the answer here. This is a fast-paced late-night fare that is well-cut, directorially, but would be so much better without the messy special effects. Here's the official trailer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bl-iB4WAB0o

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This sounds like the 1987 movie [*The Hidden*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093185/) starring Kyle McLachlan.

> An alien is on the run in America. To get his kicks, it kills anything that gets in its way, and uses the body as a new hiding place. This alien has a goal in life; power. Hotly pursued by another alien (who's borrowed the body of a dead FBI agent), lots of innocent people die in the chase.
>
> When the ordinary citizen Jack DeVries (Chris Mulkey) heists many banks and kills many people, the whole police department chases him under the command of detective Tom Beck (Michael Nouri). They capture him and seriously wounded, he is sent to the hospital, sharing a room with Jonathan Miller (William Boyett), a man with serious gastritis. The FBI agent Lloyd Gallagher (Kyle MacLachlan) comes to the police station looking for DeVries and is assigned to join Tom. When they arrive in the hospital, DeVries is dead and Jonathan is missing. This is the beginning of the hunting for a mysterious and bloody alien.

Comment: A campy, bloody mess, but one of my favorite "B" movies.

Comment: I'm gonna guess that Kyle McLachlan's character enjoys a nice cup of coffee.