# Movie about an alien (or parasite) that comes out a man's mouth and enters a woman's mouth

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I am looking for a live action movie I watched somewhere between 1980 to 2000.

The  movie had a scene where a man's tongue transformed into snake or maybe a slug (I cant remember it precisely). Then it entered a female's mouth.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Feel free to take the [Science Fiction & Fantasy tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. You can also visit this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) and subsequently add more details to your question so that it will be easier for others to find the movie you are searching for.

Comment: Where did you watch this? Where was the film made? What language? In what year? Live-action or animated?

Comment: Year 1980-2000, and it was a live-action movie

Comment: Closest I've found so far is the scene in *Cursed 2: The Bite* where the man's tongue falls out and is replaced by a snake. Does https://youtu.be/8t-BaEElZRg?t=1h27m25s look familiar?

Comment: could be "the hidden"  there is a female stripper taken by an alien https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hidden_%28film%29

Comment: @Bigben59: The review at https://youtu.be/VwcqMQf9MMk?t=3m shows one transfer, albeit male to male, and the female in question.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32244/movie-id-creature-crawls-out-of-its-current-hosts-mouth-into-next-hosts-mouth

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Movie: Creature crawls out of its current hosts mouth into next hosts mouth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32244/movie-creature-crawls-out-of-its-current-hosts-mouth-into-next-hosts-mouth)

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter No accept here so not a dupe.

Comment: We need confirmation of an answer by the OP before closing as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As per Bigben59's comment above, this may be *[The Hidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hidden_%28film%29)*, a 1987 horror film starring Kyle MacLachlan and Michael Nouri as two law officers in pursuit of a body-switching alien parasite that looks a bit like a slug. Below, you can see one of the first transfer scenes in the film:

A bit further in, they show Brenda, a stripper, being attacked by the Alien, but the review does not show it being transferred to her. That scene may exist in the complete film.

Answer (score 0):

If it was only one or two instances, it could have been [The Hidden](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093185/).

There are a number of other sf movies that use that.

I recall one with aliens that look like slugs that were transmitted that way called [Night of the Creeps](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091630/).  That had a lot of that happening.  It also had a supposed sequel called [Zombie Town](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0496444/).